# Creating one-to-many & many-to-many for same domain class in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, groovy-console

I want to create a domain class as like  , One user can post many orders [Bidirectional] and one order can be liked by many users [unidirectional].

I have written a domain class as shown below ,

```
Class User {

  String userName;

  List orders 

  static hasMany = [Order]
}

Class Order {

    String orderId

    String orderName

       //Indicates this order belongs to only one user
    static belongsTo =[owner : User ]  // Bidirectional

    //Indicates order can be liked by many users
    static hasMany = [likedUser : User]   //Unidirectional
 }
```

But I am getting am error saying invalid schema . Any body please help...

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536669/multiple-hasmany-relationships-to-same-domain-class-in-grails) looks similar to my question but I am not getting , Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `order` is a reserved word in SQL. Since GORM by default creates a table with the same name as your class, you'll need to either rename your class or provide a different name to use when mapping to SQL tables.

For example:

```
class Order {
    static mapping = {
        table 'user_order'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Another problem is that `Order` contains two associations to `User`. You need to tell GORM which one of these that is the bi-directional association from `User` to `Order`. That can be achieved using `mappedBy`, like this:

```
class User {
    String userName

    static hasMany = [orders: Order]
    static mappedBy = [orders: 'owner']

}
```

Hope this helps.